# How to send music to one output device, all other sounds to phones?

Tags: macos, audio

I would like to send music (Spotify app) to the Bluetooth speakers but keep all other sounds (notifications, etc) on the earphones.

Is this possible?
From what I can find online I need a 3rd party app (can't do it from the OS).

Most of the results are about sending all audio to multiple outputs, thus creating the output aggregate device using audio midi setup built-in app.

**Version:** MacOs Catalina 10.15.5

Answer (score 1):

Unless anyone can come up with a freeware solution, [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) is your best bet. It's about $£€ 30, depending on local tax.

[image]